# Cascade true doesn't set foreign key for record on save

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am using TypeORM version 0.3.15 with sqlite3. I have the association setup where a User belongs to one company and a Company has many users. Additionally I have added the cascade set to "insert" for a company's user. That said, when I create and save a new company, the currentUser that I include in does not add the foreign key to "companyId" field in the user's table.

Below are my entities:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  companyId: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Company, company => company.users)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'companyId' })
  company: Company;
}

@Entity()
export class Company {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => User, user => user.company, { cascade: ['insert'] })
  users: User[];
}
```

Below is the operation to create and save a Company that should update the "companyId" field in the User's record:

```
/*
  console.log of the instance of "currentUser"
  User {
  id: 1,
  email: 'user@example.com',
  company: null
}
*/

const company = this.companyRepository.create({
  ...createCompanyDto,
  users: [currentUser]
});
this.companyRepository.save(company);
```

It seems to me that by leveraging the power of cascade, this should work in a single operation. Any input as to what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated :)

**Update:**
According to ChatGPT I need to add `{ cascade: true }` to the **User.entity** like such:

```
@ManyToOne(() => Company, company => company.users, { cascade: true })
@JoinColumn({ name: 'companyId' })
company: Company;
```

But this still doesn't work :(